# How to get Platform Toolset 'v90' for Visual Studio 2017?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017-build-tools

I tried every workaround I could find. None of it worked.

Is it even possible to get Visual Studio 2008 build tools and v90 in particular for Visual Studio 2017?

What are alternatives? I need this toolset to work on some old code.

Comment: The gap between 2017 and 2008 is very wide -- VS made fundamental architecture changes about twice in that period -- so I'd go with "no". Unless you can find and old copy of VS 2008 (Express) itself (or 2010, or 2012) you'd be better off upgrading the projects/code itself manually, rather than trying to get the toolset to work. This shouldn't be too hard even if the build has custom steps. If you're trying to target platforms/runtime libs VS 2017 no longer supports (i.e. not .NET), you're *definitely* better off trying to get the actual old VS.

Comment: So if I, say, install 2008 express, will there be v90 toolset?

Comment: VS 2008 Express will include the 2008 build system, so yes (it's basically only missing VS extensibility and some premium features, and otherwise a complete VS complete with CLI tooling). And no, I wouldn't expect VS 2017 to then be able to use that toolset somehow -- it will still only be VS 2008 itself that can build the thing. If you absolutely needed to integrate it into a 2017 build, you could use a separate step to invoke the 2008 tools separately.

Comment: Thank you, could you make it an answer so I can mark it correctly?

Comment: VS2008 is end of life, https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudio/2017/04/10/end-of-support-for-visual-studio-2008-in-one-year/ There were efforts to support old VC++ releases in VS2010, https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=OwenWengerd.DaffodilforVisualStudio which was further extended to VS2012 and above, https://github.com/Georgeto/Daffodil So if you really have a need to use end-of-life products, you can help yourself.